# sqlalchemy - Mapper mapped class X->y could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table y

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to add two more tables via ORM to an already existing MySQL database. The tables I'm trying to add are `DataInfo` and `Project`, the already existing table is `User`. As you can see, my `Project` table has a ForeignKey to the `User` table but whenever I run the code, I get the error `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper mapped class User->d_users could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'd_users'`. I followed some tutorials online but couldn't solve my problem.

This is my models.py file.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Date, MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from .database import Base

from datetime import datetime

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "d_users"


class DataInfo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "d_data_info"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    isURL = Column(Integer, index=True)
    dataSource = Column(String(100), index=True)
    dateCreated = Column(Date, index=True, default=datetime.date(datetime.now()))
    projectId = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("d_ml_projects.projectId"))

    data_for_project = relationship("Project", back_populates="data")


class Project(Base):
    __tablename__ = "d_ml_projects"

    projectId = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    projectTitle = Column(String(200), index=True)
    projectDescription = Column(String(550), index=True)
    problemType = Column(String(15), index=True)
    classLabel = Column(String(100), index=True)

    userId = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("d_users.id"))
    data = relationship("DataInfo", back_populates="data_for_project")
```

database.py:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "mysql+pymysql://martin:password@localhost/hope"

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL
)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()
```

My `DESCRIBE d_users` from MySQL;

```
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id                | varchar(36)  | NO   | PRI | NULL              |                             |
| oAuthId           | varchar(48)  | NO   | UNI | NULL              |                             |
| oAuthType         | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| firstName         | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| secondName        | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| city              | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| phone             | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| email             | varchar(100) | YES  | UNI | NULL              |                             |
| profileLink       | varchar(300) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| profilePic        | varchar(300) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| status            | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| notificationToken | text         | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| password          | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| confirmed         | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 0                 |                             |
| notes             | text         | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| created_timestamp | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                             |
| updated_timestamp | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: You have not defined _any_ columns in the `User` model, so it follows that it cannot assemble any primary key columns. Did you mean to use reflection?

Comment: @IljaEverilä have solved it using `class User(Base):
    __table__ = Table('d_users', Base.metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)`. Now I'm facing with another error which says `sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1215, 'Cannot add foreign key constraint')` for the `Project` table. Do you know what can cause this error?

Comment: User id seems to be a string, but your project is using an integer.

Comment: oh you're so right. Changed it and it works like a charm, thank you @IljaEverilä